# How to use probability mass functions to find probability mass function and moment generating function of Z?

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables such that

$p_{(x)}(x) = \frac{1}{3}, x = -1,0,1$

$p_{(y)}(y) = \frac{1}{2}, y = 2,4$

Let's say $Z = X + Y$.
I am trying to find the probability mass function of $Z$ using what I know about $X$ and $Y$, their functions above. Here's my intuition, I think

$p_{(z)}(z) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{6}$. But how do I know the values $z$ can take on? Is it the all values of $x$ and $y$ together? So, $,-1,0,1,2,4$. This seems reasonable to think. Also, I want to determine the moment generating function of $Z$. I figured there should be a way to use it's probability mass function once found. But is it possible to find a moment generating function from it's probability mass function, I can't see how? Typically, you're given both but with one missing, I can't see any idea on how to solve anything without it. Any ideas?

Comment: I just read your four questions on the site and they left me with an odd feeling: you repeatedly appeal to your intuition and seem completely unaware of any solid definition of the concepts involved; are you using some kind of textbook?

Comment: @Did Yeah, I am using this textbook Scheaffer & Young: Introduction to Probability and It's Applications. This isn't my area of expertise but I trying to get better at connecting the various ideas with problems, cause I feel to solve some problems you need to solve smaller ones prior but those smaller ones require other concrete concepts? Hope this doesn't sound too wordy. I'm hesitant, thats all, sorry.

Comment: And nowhere do they explain how to compute the PMF of a sum of (independent) random variables with known PMFs?

Comment: @Did  TBH, I couldn't find it in the textbook anywhere.

Comment: Amazingly the authors manage to avoid this, yes (no idea of their reasons for this strange choice). But, true to its focus on generating functions, the book does explain that, *assuming independence*, $E(t^Z)=E(t^X)E(t^Y)$ for every $t$. In your case, $E(t^X)=\frac13(t+1+t^{-1})$, $E(t^Y)=\frac12(t^2+t^4)$, hence $E(t^Z)=\frac13(t+1+t^{-1})\frac12(t^2+t^4)=\frac16t(t^2+t+1)(t^2+1)=\frac16(t^5+t^4+2t^3+t^2+t)$, thus, the *methods of your book* directly yield that the PMF of $Z$ is $p_Z(5)=p_Z(4)=p_Z(2)=p_Z(1)=\frac16$ and $p_Z(3)=\frac13$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. This is not mentioned explicitly, but the problem cannot be solved if we do not have information about possible dependencies between $X$ and $Y$.

The moment generating function of $X$ is $E(e^{tX})$. We have $e^{tX}=e^{-t}$, $1$, or $e^t$, each with probability $\frac{1}{3}$. Thus the moment generating function $M_X(t)$ of $X$ is given by
$$M_X(t)=\frac{1}{3}e^{-t}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}e^t.$$
The moment generating function of $Y$ is found in a similar way.

For the moment generating function of $Z$, use the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are *independent*, then 
$$M_{X+Y}(t)=M_X(t)M_Y(t).$$

*Added*: We could also first find the probability mass function of $Z$, and then find the mgf. Let us start on finding the mass function of $Z$, in order to clear up possible misconceptions.

The random variable $X+Y$ takes on possible values $-1+2,-1+4,0+2,0+4,1+2, 1+4$, or more simply $1,2,3,4,5$. To find the pobability mass function of $Z$, we calculate $\Pr(Z=z)$ for each of these possible values.

For example, we have $Z=1$ precisely if $X=-1$ **and** $Y=2$. This has probability $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$.

The other probabilities are computed in a similar way. But note that we can have $Z=3$ in two ways, $X=-1$ and $Y=4$ or $X=1$ and $Y=2$. Thus $\Pr(Z=3)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$.

You should end up with the conclusion that $\Pr(Z=z)=\frac{1}{6}$ for $z=1,2,4,5$, and $\Pr(Z=z)=\frac{2}{6}$ for $z=3$.